# How to creating object with long(integer) as parameter in Bluej

Tags: java

I am facing a problem while trying to create object with long(integer) as parameter for Number class it says "Error: integer number to large." in Bluej.

```
 /**
 * A class that represents a number and can report
 * properties of the number.
 */
public class Number
{
    private long number;

    public Number(long number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of times digitToMatch appears
     * in this number.
     * @param digitToMatch the digit to search for.
     *   must be at least 0 and at most 9.
     * @return number of occurrences of digitToMatch
     */
    public int countMatchingDigits(int digitToMatch)
    {
        // TODO: count and return the number of times the given digit appears in the number
        int count = 0;
        if(digitToMatch >= 0 && digitToMatch <= 9)
        {
            long n = 0;
            while(number > 0)
            {
                n = number % 10;
                if(n == digitToMatch)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                number = number / 10;
            }

        }
        // Hint: The last digit is (int)(numbers % 10).
         return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you declaring number? My guess is that you're declaring it as an int, which would be the problem...

Comment: the above two line of code which is not shown is :-

Comment: I have declared instance variable "private long number";